# Add custom html tags in react native WebView

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview

I am currently rendering the HTML content in Webview. That HTML content hosted in cloud and loading in Webview using the html link. Here, I need to add the below checkbox tags in that content while dynamically rendering or I need to show the checkbox on bottom of the page.

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="agreement_id" name="agreement" value="agreement">
    <label for="other">I have read and accept the Electronic Communications Agreement consenting to the use of Electronic Records in connection with opening my new deposit credit accounts requested through the Swell mobile app.</label>
</div>
```

Is any possible to add programmatically in react native Webview?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer here: Used `injectedJavaScript`.

```
const scripts1 = document.write(
  '<div> <input type="checkbox" id="agreement_id" name="agreement" value="agreement"> <label for="other">content</label> </div>',
);

const webviewContent = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: windowHeight - heightBottom * 1.5,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
      }}>
      <WebView
        style={{backgroundColor: colors.primaryBackgroundColor}}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://www.google.com',
        }}
        injectedJavaScript={scripts1}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```